# InfoPath 2007 Dataconnection not executing (works in C#, not VB.NET)

Tags: .net, infopath

Greetings,

I have an InfoPath 2007 form, for which the programming for parts of the form (mostly changed events) were done in C#.  I am trying to convert these to VB, but, I am having an issue with DataConnection.Execute()

The original C# code seen below:

```
XPathNavigator main = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator mainStart = main.SelectSingleNode("*xPath*", NamespaceManager);
string strWO = mainStart.Value.ToString();

DataSource ds = DataSources["Discrepancies"];
XPathNavigator xnds = ds.CreateNavigator();
xnds.SelectSingleNode("*xPath*", NamespaceManager).SetValue(strWO);

DataConnection dc = ds.QueryConnection;
dc.Execute();

XPathNavigator nvgFaults = DataSources["Discrepancies"].CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator faultNodes = nvgFaults.Select("*xpath*", NamespaceManager);

while (faultNodes.MoveNext())
      {
      string nodeSequence = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("ACTION_SEQUENCE", NamespaceManager).Value;
      string nodeFault = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("FAULT_NOTES", NamespaceManager).Value;
      string nodeAction = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("ACTION_NOTES", NamespaceManager).Value;

      writer.WriteStartElement("group4", myNameSpace);
      writer.WriteElementString("txtSequence", myNameSpace, nodeSequence);
      writer.WriteElementString("txtFault", myNameSpace, nodeFault);
      writer.WriteElementString("txtAction", myNameSpace, nodeAction);
      writer.WriteEndElement();
      }
```

Executes properly, filling my form as expected, but, the VB code, shown below, does not:

```
Dim main As XPathNavigator = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator()
Dim mainStart As XPathNavigator = main.SelectSingleNode("*xPath*", NamespaceManager)
Dim strWO As String = mainStart.Value.ToString

Dim dsresult As DataSource = DataSources("Discrepancies")
Dim xNav As XPathNavigator = dsresult.CreateNavigator()
xNav.SelectSingleNode("*xPath*", NamespaceManager).SetValue(strWO)

Dim dataConn As DataConnection = dsresult.QueryConnection()
dataConn.Execute()

Dim navFaults As XPathNavigator = DataSources("Discrepancies").CreateNavigator()
Dim faultNodes As XPathNodeIterator = navFaults.Select("*xPath*", NamespaceManager)

Dim myNameSpace As String = NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my")

While faultNodes.MoveNext()
       Dim nodeSequence As String = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("ACTION_SEQUENCE", NamespaceManager).Value
       Dim nodeFault As String = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("FAULT_NOTES", NamespaceManager).Value
       Dim nodeAction As String = faultNodes.Current.SelectSingleNode("ACTION_NOTES", NamespaceManager).Value

       Using writer As XmlWriter = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator(). _
       SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:group1", NamespaceManager).AppendChild()

              writer.WriteStartElement("group2", myNameSpace)
              writer.WriteElementString("txtSequence", myNameSpace, nodeSequence)
              writer.WriteElementString("txtFault", myNameSpace, nodeFault)
              writer.WriteElementString("txtAction", myNameSpace, nodeAction)
              writer.WriteEndElement()
              writer.Close()
        End Using
End While
```

I have run several tests (not illustrated in the examples) to prove that I am, in fact, getting the proper variables, such as 'strWO'.  This variable is then passed to the DataSource "Discrepancies", which is a stored procedure.

If I invoke the SP Discrepancies through my WebMethod (also converted to VB), it does in fact, return the information it should.  That is all well and good.  I get the information that I expect.

But, the VB version, does not execute the query.  Doing a simple test on node counts, I get '0.'  Whereas the particular item I am testing, should return a node count in the low 40's.  There is data to be had, yet, I cannot get the query to execute.  And it's driving me mad.

Some of the variable names are different from c# to vb, as well as some infoPath xPaths, which I have simplified down to just *xpath* for readability.  Some of those xPaths get pretty long. But, I am positive that any variable name changes are consistent.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for stating the obvious, I assume the you have setup the datasource discrepencies to recieve data?

Comment: Nathan, yes it is set up to receive data, but, after making sure that I was right in telling you that; I noticed a small discrepancy (not to be confused with the datasource name discrepancies) in the schema between the two 'versions' and that is where my error was occurring and why it was not executing.  Once that was fixed, all was good.